# how to fix release testing warning with ad_id permission

Tags: android, testing, admob, warnings

I am having kotlin android project and i have cleared all issues but I am having only one warning in play console as shown in below screenshot. pls help anyone to fix this issue. I have declared ad id permission  and application id also in manifest xml. But still warning exists in play console. For your reference i have attached ad id declaration page also.

[image]

In manifest, i have added ad permission as

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

ad application id also added in the manifest xml.

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx" />
```

But still i am getting this warning in console.

ad id declaration page screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. In android manifest add ad permission

   ```
       <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

   `  <application
           android:name=".MyApplication"
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name_short">

        <meta-data
               android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
               android:value="@string/admob_app_id" />

      </application>
   ```
2. Gradle scripts Gradle build (Module :app) Add  compile SDK 33, target SDK 33

   android {
   namespace 'com.abc'
   compileSdk 33

   ```
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.abc"
           minSdk 19
           targetSdk 33
           versionCode 0001
           versionName "0.00.00.build.0001"
       }
   ```

   }
3. Manage Advertising ID in App content (Yes)
4. New release just increment version name and code.